# I can't see the number of rows in the table correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem in correctly displaying the number of rows in the table.

In particular, `rowCount` is always equal to 1.

Can anyone kindly help me?

```js
let table = document.getElementById("my-table");
allart.Items.forEach(function (item) {
let child = document.createElement("tr");
child.innerHTML = `
<td>${item.id}</td>
<td>${item.title}</a></td>
<td>${item.brand}</td>
table.appendChild(child);
}

var table = document.getElementById(my-table).tBodies[0];
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
```

```html
<table id = "my-table" width = "90%">
         <tr>
             <th> Id </th>
             <th> Title </th>
             <th> Brand </th>
         </tr>

 </table>
```

Regarding the javascript code, I only put the code of interest because the whole code is too long

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('table#my-table tr').length` should return the amount of `<tr>` in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:
tBodies will give you how many tbody tags () you are having in your HTML and it is not related to how many rows. As the reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table3

If you want to see how many rows you have in your table you can use this code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("my-table").rows.length;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always returns 1. While in my table there are 6 rows (including header row)

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a I have edited the answer, it is working for me and I hope also for you